# Is it possible to run ARKit in simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, arkit

I tried to run sample **ARKit** in Xcode 9 iPhone 7 plus simulator. But it failed. Is there any possibilities to check ARKit projects in iOS simulators.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ARKit uses the camera as well as gyroscope and accelerometer to map the world and get the device's relative position, so no you won't be able to use it in the simulator.

Comment: I wonder if MacBooks still have motion sensors now that they don't have hard disks anymore? (They used to be there for parking the drive heads when free fall is detected.) Regardless, the camera/sensor suite in a Mac probably isn't enough to do what ARKit needs, nor worth Apple's time to calibrate...

Comment: Even if the macbook had motion sensors, they are not accessible in the simulator right (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html) ?

Comment: Right. That was sort of an offhand comment about whether/how *Apple* could make the simulator pretend it has an accelerometer.

Comment: It'd be very cool if the did that for the camera with the webcam but hey..

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it is not possible because the basic requirement to run ARKit is camera access.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet ... **BUT** ... Google might show the way.

You can run Android ARCore in the Emulator.  I run it on my Mac. 
https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator

ARCore and ARKit follow the same basic IMU-SLAM architecture.  So I believe it is technically possible and I hope Apple follows suit.